# Column ranges contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY when using CASE, arrays and structs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm not writing the whole query (which involves CTE's, that is a little bit long), but in the end, I have this query:

```
select 
ARRAY_TO_STRING((select sector from unnest(place)),"") as sector,
[struct(array_agg(
(case
  when age <= 25 then "18-25"
  when age >= 26 and age <= 35 then "26-35"
  when age >= 36 and age <= 45 then "36-45"
  when age >= 46 and age <= 55 then "46-55"
  when age >= 56 and age <= 66 then "56-65"
  when age >= 66 and age <= 75 then "66-75"
  else "75+"
end)) as age_range)] as ranges,count(*) from males
group by sector
```

that gives me this output:

```
Row   sector    ranges.age_range f0_    
1   Los Dominicos   46-55        5645
                    56-65
                    56-65
                    46-55
                    46-55
                    36-45
                    36-45
                    26-35
                    26-35
                    26-35
                    66-75
                    66-75
                    66-75
                    46-55
                    56-65
                    66-75
                    66-75
                    56-65
                    66-75
                    26-35
                    56-65
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

I would like to group also by ranges, but when I do I get the following error:

```
Column ranges contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY
```

What I want to get is something like this:

```
Row   sector    ranges.age_range   f0_  
1   Los Dominicos   18-25          5645
                    26-35          6846
                    36-45          79621
                    46-55          3215
                    56-65          3121
                    66-75          1324
                    75+            160
```

This values in column `f0_` should be the amount of people that belong to `Los Dominicos` and are part of each age range.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: I'm adding part of the CTE, because I think that there is something that I forgot to put here.

```
...
las_condes as (
select a.id, edad, t.nombre,t.gender,
[struct(array_agg(sector limit 1) as sector)] as places from all_tables a inner join 
table t on a.id = t.id
where comuna = "las condes" and t.gender is not null
group by t.id,age,t.name,t.gender
),
female as (
select * from las_condes where gender = false
),
male as (
select * from las_condes where gender = true
)

...
```

So, `sector` is really `places.sector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two levels of aggregation:

```
select sector,
       array_agg(struct(age_range, cnt))
from (select ARRAY_TO_STRING((select sector from unnest(place)), '') as sector,
             (case when age <= 25 then '18-25'
                   when age >= 26 and age <= 35 then '26-35'
                   when age >= 36 and age <= 45 then '36-45'
                   when age >= 46 and age <= 55 then '46-55'
                   when age >= 56 and age <= 66 then '56-65'
                   when age >= 66 and age <= 75 then '66-75'
                   else '75+'
               end) as age_range, count(*) as cnt
      from males m
      group by sector, age_range
     ) m
group by sector;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff. I tried your answer but it does not recognize the word `sector` inside the second `select`. I also added a part of the CTE which I forgot to add and I think it might be useful. Please, let me know if more information is needed :)

Comment: @PedroPabloSeverinHonorato . . . You have the expression for `sector` in your code.  I added it in here.

Comment: You are right...sorry I missed that and thank you for your answer